# Embed Matplotlib into HWND

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, winapi, embed

After scouring the web for a while now, it seems its possible to embed Python into tkinter, qt5, etc. however, I am wondering if it is possible to simply embed it into a Windows application. Similar to how Jupyter embeds with `%matplotlib inline`, I am wondering if a similar functionality is possible for Window applications.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <python.h>

LPARAM CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
  switch (msg) {
  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
  }
}

#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup")
#pragma warning(suppress: 28251) // Inconsistent Annotation Suppression
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  WNDCLASSEX wc = {};

  wc.lpszClassName = "customWindow";
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

  RegisterClassEx(&wc);

  HWND hwnd = CreateWindow("customWindow", "Testing embedded matplotlib", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 1000, 1000, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
  UpdateWindow(hwnd);
  ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

  Py_Initialize();

  const char* code =
    R"(
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)))
plt.show()
)";

  PyRun_SimpleString(code);

  Py_Finalize();

  MSG message;
  while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
  {
    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessage(&message);
  }

  return static_cast<int>(message.wParam);
}
```

In this incomplete example (separate matplotlib window opens separately), I'd like to figure out if its possible to reparent matplotlib's window into the master hwnd. Ideally, I'd like to still have matplotlib's interactivity so trying to do a bitblt from an internal matplotlib buffer is not feasible for me.

Comment: What is sure not possible is to use `pyplot` for that matter. Possibly someone wrote a backend which is suitable for that purpose.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'd prefer if it were possible with just native libraries, but what do you mean that it is not possible with 'pyplot'.

Comment: You cannot have your figure managed by pyplot and another application at the same time. See e.g. [the example about embedding in pyqt](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html); it does explicitely not use pyplot.

Comment: If you want to change the parent window of matplotlib's window maybe you can try [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) function.